# Micronaut unit test - how to set default schema

Tags: java, junit5, hikaricp, micronaut, micronaut-data

I tried to use unit test but could not find the way to set the `default schema`  in this sample application.
This is a simple `micronaut-data` [example](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/) having `model`, `repository` and `service`. HSQL database is used in application, and Hikari db-pool `micronaut-jdbc-hikari`

**Model**: `Student.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student") 
class Student{

  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;   

  @Column(name="name")     
  private String name;

  public Long getId(){
    return this.id;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  public void setId(Long id){
    this.id = id;
  }
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

**Repository**: `StudentRepository.java`

```
@Repository()
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

**Service**: `StudentService.java`

```
@Singleton
public class StudentService {

    @Inject
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public Student getStudentById(Long id) {
        Optional<Student> optional = StudentRepository.findById(id);
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            return optional.get();
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("No matching data available");
    }

}
```

**Unit test**: `StudentServiceTest.java`

```
@MicronautTest
public class StudentServiceTest {

    @RegisterExtension
    static InMemoryDbExtension inMemoryDbExtension = new InMemoryDbExtension.InMemoryDbBuilder()
            .withSchemaName("TEST_SCHEMA")
            .withSchemaSqls(new String[]{"src/test/resources/memdb/schema.sql"})
            .withTestDataSqls(new String[]{"src/test/resources/db/test.sql"})
            .build();
    private static InMemoryHsqlDb inMemoryHsqlDb;
    @Inject
    private StudentService studentService;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void runBeforeAll(InMemoryHsqlDb inMemoryHsqlDb) {
        StudentServiceTest.inMemoryHsqlDb = inMemoryHsqlDb;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldTestGetById() {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setId(5);
        s.setName("XYZ");
        studentService.save(s); // query generated: insert into student(id, name) values (?,?)
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
There are some ways I could find where we can set the default schema, but each has it's problem.

1. Using repository annotation `@Table(schema="TEST_SCHEMA", name="student")` <= Works. But can't hardcode schema name
2. Using repository annotation `@Table(schema="#{property.file.schema_name}", name="student")` <= Spring expressions, SpEL doesn't work

3.Using `application-test.yml` file: [It has not effect, query doesn't pick schema name ].

```
jpa:
      default:
        entity-scan:
          packages: 'com.example.model'
          properties:
            hibernate:
              hbm2ddl:
                auto: update
              default-schema: TEST_SCHEMA # <= default schema, also tried default_schema
              show_sql: true
```

4.Using `application-test.yml` file specifying schema in datasource:
But it doesn't work because the schema is yet to be created, it will create in test-class. So application doesn't load.

```
datasources:
  default:
    driverClass: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
    url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true
    username: sa
    autoCommit: false
    maximumPoolSize: 1
    leakDetectionThreshold: 180000
    poolName: hikariConnectionPoolName
    minimumIdle: 5
    schema: TEST_SCHEMA  # <= default schema
```

=========================================================
**Workaround for now**

Use synonym as `table_name` for `schema_name.table_name`
So, when query is created without schema, synonym will be replaced. Generate synonym as `student` for `test_schema.student`

**So that query will be translated properly:**

Generated query => `insert into student(id, name) values (?,?)`

Translated query => `insert into test_schema.student(id, name) values (?,?)`

**Unit test**: `StudentServiceTest.java`

```
@BeforeAll
    public static void runBeforeAll(InMemoryHsqlDb inMemoryHsqlDb) {
        StudentServiceTest.inMemoryHsqlDb = inMemoryHsqlDb;
        // workaround for not using schema
        inMemoryHsqlDb.getJdbi().open().execute("create synonym STUDENT for TEST_SCHEMA.STUDENT");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `schema="#{property.file.schema_name}"` have you tried `schema="${property.file.schema_name}"`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes I have tried that as well. But it also doesn't work. It takes complete word as-it-is for schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to execute a script when you init the database, and load the schema when the database is loaded:

In the application-test.yml, you can change the datasource configuration:

```
datasources:
  default:
    driverClass: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
    url: "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/init_db.sql'"
    username: sa
    autoCommit: false
    maximumPoolSize: 1
    leakDetectionThreshold: 180000
    poolName: hikariConnectionPoolName
    minimumIdle: 5
```

The line

```
url: "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_ora=true;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:/init_db.sql'"
```

will start the datasource with an init sql script who can contain the default schema, and some data if needed. The downside of this method is that the database is initialized only once before the unit test start, so you have to keep that in mind.

the init_db.sql scprit has to be in the test resource folder and should contain the content of both scripts "src/test/resources/memdb/schema.sql" and "src/test/resources/db/test.sql"

Then the unit test become

```
@MicronautTest
public class StudentServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Test
    public void shouldTestGetById() {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setId(5);
        s.setName("XYZ");
        studentService.save(s); // query generated: insert into student(id, name) values (?,?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official docu there is something about [GORM](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#multitenancyGorm). Can this maybe help yout with your problem?